# How to Update Multiple Fields at Once with HQL?

Tags: hibernate, hql

There's no problem with updating one field at a time:

```
hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery("UPDATE User set email='" + email+ "' where id='" + userId + "' ").executeUpdate();
```

But what if I want to update multiple fields at once? I added "AND" between the parameters but it didn't work:

```
hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery("UPDATE User set email='" + email+ "' AND firstName= '" + firstname + "' AND lastName= '"+lastname+"' AND password= '" + mdp + "' where id='" + userId + "' ").executeUpdate();
```

Could you please tell me how can I update many fields at once using HQL? Thanks.

Comment: I guess this is based on SQL, then it is "," that you should put instead of "AND" behind the SET.
Check this link : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Comment: That was it. Thanks a lot. Could you please add you comment as an answer so I can upvote it and choose it as the correct one? Thanks.

Comment: That is not the JPA API. Kindly dont tag it as the JPA API. If you don't know what API you're using then use internet search

Comment: Done :) Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is based on SQL, then it is "," that you should put instead of "AND" behind the SET. 
Check this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp).